# Metric spaces: prove the existence of disjoint neighborhood of closed set.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Can someone help me with this exercise?

Let (X,d) be a metric space. E,F are two disjoint closed set. Prove that there exist two open set U,G such that $E\subset U$ and $F\subset G$ and their closure ($\bar{U}$ and $\bar{G}$) are disjoint.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You may also like to prove a stronger statement that $E$ and $F$ are separated by a continuous function. That is, there is continuous function $f: X\rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $f(E)=\{0\}$, $f(F)=\{1\}$. Then it follows that $E$ is in $f^{-1}[0,1/2)$ which is open in [0,1]…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In any metric space $(X,d)$ the function $x \to d(x,A)$ is continuous (in $x$ from $X$ to the reals), for any subset $A$. Then define, for $E$ and $F$ disjoint and closed the function

$$f(x) = \frac{d(x,E)}{d(x,E) + d(x,F)}$$

which is well-defined for all $x$, as for closed sets $C$, $d(x,C) = 0$ iff $x \in C$, and otherwise $d(x, C) >0$. This means that below in the fraction we never get $0$ (otherwise $d(x,E)  =0 = d(x,F)$ which would mean $x \in E \cap F = \emptyset$, so this cannot happen).
So $f$ is continuous and $f[E] = \{0\}$ and $f[F]  =\{1\}$ So

$$U = f^{-1}[(-\infty, \frac{1}{3})] ,V = f^{-1}[(\frac{1}{3}, +\infty)]$$

are open and disjoint, while $E \subseteq U, F \subseteq V$ and as $\overline{U} \subseteq f^{-1}[(-\infty, \frac{1}{3}]]$ and   $\overline{V} \subseteq   f^{-1}[[\frac{1}{3}, +\infty)]$, their closures are also disjoint.

Answer (score 2):

Draw a picture!  Intuition from $\mathbb{R}^2$ goes a long way here.

Since $E$ and $F$ are disjoint closed sets, then for any $x \in E$, we have $\text{inf} \{d(x,y)  \ | \ y \in F \} = r_x > 0$.  This is good, because it means that for each $x \in E$, we can draw an open ball $B_x$ centered at $x$ with radius less than $r_x/2$--thus ensuring that each $B_x$ is "far" from $F$.

Let the open set containing $E$ be $\displaystyle U = \bigcup_{x \in E} B_x$.

I'll let you fill in the rest of the details.  How can we build an open set $V$ containing $F$ so that $U$ and $V$ are disjoint?  While building $V$, you can use some trickery similar to how we built $U$ to ensure that the closures of $U$ and $V$ are disjoint -- after all, we ensured that $U$ is still "far" from $F$ itself.  It can't be too difficult to ensure that the $V$ we construct is "far" from $U$.

Again, drawing a picture in the plane with the usual metric gives all the intuition one needs--even if the metric space in question is something unfamiliar.